# Stop audio without closing my application in android

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I m new to develop android application.
I need to play an audio when my application is opened.
And i placed a stop Audio button to stop audio.
This is the code i used.

```
@TargetApi(9)
public void PlayAudio()
{
        AudioManager audioPlayer=(AudioManager)this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        audioPlayer.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        int maxVolume = audioPlayer.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        audioPlayer.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, maxVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        media=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.idhayam);
        media.start();
}

public void StopMedia(View view)
{
    if(media.isPlaying())
    {
        media.pause();
    }
}
```

}

When i trigger "Off media", the audio gets stopped also my application gets stopped unfortunately.
How to stop audio without closing my application.

Comment: In your query, you have mentioned about `OffMedia` and in the code snippet, you show `StopMedia`. Are these 2 functions the same?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to create the `MediaPlayer` in a separate service. Please refer to the answer by MalaKa to this question: [Thread and mediaplayer problems, Timer with sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15502123/thread-and-mediaplayer-problems-timer-with-sound) which will help you to solve your problem