# Thread and mediaplayer problems, Timer with sound

Tags: android, multithreading, audio, media-player, timertask

I'm developing an Android application that is based on a timer that every second must play a sound that you selected before.

Here is the problem:

- No  objects can run `Media Player` in a `Thread` or a `Runnable`
- I can not call methods that reproduce the sound
- I can not run it on a timer task

Can you think of anything?

Thanks

thread:

public void run(){
        while(!detenido) //Bolean for stop the thread
          {

```
        try {
            Servicio servicios = new Servicio();
            switch(segundosesperar){ //Int to select the ms to slep
            case 0:
                this.sleep(1500);
                servicios.intento1(); //the metod with " mp.start()"
                dormir = 1500;
                break;
            case 1:
                this.sleep(1600);
                servicios.intento1();
                dormir = 1600;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.sleep(1700);
                servicios.intento1();
                dormir = 1700;
                break;
            case 3:
                this.sleep(1800);
                servicios.intento1();
                dormir = 1800;
                break;
            case 4:
                this.sleep(1900);
                servicios.intento1();
                dormir = 1900;
                break;
            case 5:
                this.sleep(2000);
                servicios.intento1();
                dormir = 2000;
                break;
            default:
                this.sleep(1750);
                servicios.intento1();
                dormir = 1750;
                break;

            }

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         piedras =piedras+1; //Counter cronometer +1
         cron = piedras+""; 
         //Set the counter in the activity
            handler.setHcron(cron);
            handler.act();


            cronoparaganar = cron;


            if ( piedras == piedrasmodo){
                tocarsirena = true;
            }
          } 
            }
```

Metod in the service to start a play sound:

public void intento1(){

```
    mp= MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.censura);
    mp.start();

}
```

Comment: Can you please share some code which you have tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run a `MediaPlayer` in an extra `Service`.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) out for information about `Service`.
Also, [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices) might be useful to handle the `MediaPlayer` with a `Service`.

You could then call the functions of your `Service` to handle the `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: You mean from the thread to call the service method that reproduces the sound?

Comment: Yes, you might call a Thread that waits for a second and then calls a function. This might not be the best version to handle the problem, but it should work.

Comment: i do it, but no works, see the code in the description ( i already edit the post)

Comment: you first have to start the service out of your activity. have a look [here](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-programming-tutorials/use-of-services/) to see how to handle services